# Can anyone give me a specific example of how to webscrape certain parts of HTML code

Tags: python, html, html-table

Current code:

```
print(soup.find('table', class_='shop-single-1-table').text.replace(' ', ''))
```

Returns everything inside table with class "shop-single-1-table"

This is the HTML code of the site I'm trying to scrape:

```
<table class="shop-single-1-table"><tbody><tr><td>Zustand <span class="form-tooltip"><a href="#" data-hystmodal="#frame-info-modal2"><img src="/img/iconsQ2.png" alt="" width="17" height="17"></a></span></td> <th>Sehr gut</th></tr> <tr><td>Schaltgruppe <span class="form-tooltip"></span></td> <th>Shimano Dura Ace</th></tr> <tr><td>Ort</td> <th>Köln, Deutschland</th></tr> <tr><td>Größe <span class="form-tooltip"><a href="#" data-hystmodal="#size-modal2"><img src="/img/iconsQ2.png" alt="" width="17" height="17"></a></span></td> <th>56</th></tr></tbody></table>
```

What would be a better way to, e.g. get the "Schaltgruppe" out without printing the rest?

Comment: If you already know the string you want to extract then you don't need to extract it. In other words: what exactly is your criterion for extracting this specific string?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Due to the lack of detail, the answer can only point in a direction of how to scrape the information in context*

Assuming it is the type of Schaltgruppe you like to extract, cause it makes no sense to extract a string you already know.

To achieve this you can select the `<td>` that contains the string:

```
soup.select_one('table.shop-single-1-table td:-soup-contains("Schaltgruppe") + th').text
```

or you convert the contents to a dict and get the type by key Schaltgruppe:

```
dict(list(row.stripped_strings) for row in soup.select('table.shop-single-1-table tr')).get('Schaltgruppe')
```

Output:

```
Shimano Dura Ace
```